# Changing OS X bash/terminal to a dark scheme

Tags: macos, terminal.app

I followed the directions [here](http://www.nightlion.net/themes/2010/osx-terminal-theme/) and the colors are correctly showing, however the background is still white, what else do I need to do?

Note: I did a sudo nano ./bash_profile instead of .bashrc

Comment: First of all, do not, ***do not*** use `sudo` unless you absolutely have to. Editing your `~/.bash_profile` ***does not require super user permissions.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the terminal click the Shell menu, then click the Show Inspector menu item. Alternatively, you can press Command-I. In the inspector, click the Settings button, then select a dark setting such as "Pro".

If you want to customize each the settings (font face, font size, background color, ...) then press Command-, for the preferences, then click the Settings at the top. You can now customize existing settings, or you can add your own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the settings in Terminal itself, rather than in your login or bash startup scripts.  I forget exactly where it is, but if you look for Preferences in the menus for Terminal and look for Colors - I think it's in a small window as a dropdown selector - then you can change all the colors, including the default background color.